# iOS separate scrollView & collectionView delegates into individual files

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and want to be able to perform custom behaviour when the user scrolls through implementing the scrollView delegate methods. Is it possible to have two separate objects that act as the collectionView delegate and scrollView delegate when working with a collectionView?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot have separate delegates. `UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`, and overrides its `delegate` property to change its type to `UICollectionViewDelegate` (which is a subtype of `UIScrollViewDelegate`). So you can only assign one delegate to a collection view, and it may implement any combination of `UICollectionViewDelegate` methods and `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.

However, you can forward the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to another object without much difficulty. Here's how you'd do it in Swift; it would be very similar in Objective-C (since this is all done using the Objective-C runtime):

```
import UIKit
import ObjectiveC

class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let scrollViewDelegate = MyScrollViewDelegate()

    override func respondsToSelector(aSelector: Selector) -> Bool {
        if protocol_getMethodDescription(UIScrollViewDelegate.self, aSelector, false, true).types != nil || protocol_getMethodDescription(UIScrollViewDelegate.self, aSelector, true, true).types != nil {
            return scrollViewDelegate.respondsToSelector(aSelector)
        } else {
            return super.respondsToSelector(aSelector)
        }
    }

    override func forwardingTargetForSelector(aSelector: Selector) -> AnyObject? {
        if protocol_getMethodDescription(UIScrollViewDelegate.self, aSelector, false, true).types != nil || protocol_getMethodDescription(UIScrollViewDelegate.self, aSelector, true, true).types != nil {
            return scrollViewDelegate
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Note that `MyScrollViewDelegate` probably has to be a subclass of `NSObject` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you just need your view controller to subclass UICollectionViewController or UICollectionViewDelegate. Then you can access the scrollView delegate methods since they are inherited by the collectionView

Answer (score 0):

Create subclass of UICollectionViewController and write scroll view delegates into it.

```
class CustomCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    }
}
```

In your target class

```
class MyCollectionViewController: CustomCollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
      return 1
    }


    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return 100
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath)

      return cell
    }
}
```